# macOS freezes and then reboots after running ls in mounted EFS volume

Tags: macos, amazon-efs

what is a proper way to mount AWS EFS in macOS Catalina? I found the following command:

```sh
sudo mount -t nfs -o vers=4 -o tcp -w 10.11.xx.xxx:/ ~/Desktop/efs
```

I have OpenVPN configured. The above command works however when I try to run `ls` or `rm` files, macOS freezes and then reboots. Basically, I can copy files to EFS or create new ones, but cannot list or remove them.

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: I'm experiencing this same problem with EFS, using Catalina (10.15.7) w/ OpenVPN server running in AWS, using Viscosity client.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue with macOS Catalina.

upgrading to macOS Big Sur solved it.